# jQuery val undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of an input element on a html page using jQuery. I can get the element value using .val() if I call it from a script tag in the html page. However, when I call the same function from a seperate js file it returns **undefined**.

Anyone have anyidea what is going on here?

**index.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($("#amount").val());    //  This works
  externalFunction();                   //  This returns undefined
});
```

**file.js**

```
function externalFunction() {
  console.log($("#amount").val());
}
```

**EDIT**

I should clarify that the div which contains the input element is hidden.

```
style="display: none;"
```

Would this make a difference?

Comment: What you're describing, as described, is impossible. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: Do you received any errors ?

Comment: Are you correctly including the external file?  Put at the top of the file `alert("externalfile.js")` (as the very first line).  If you don't get the alert when you load your page, you're not getting the file.  If you are getting the alert, then there's another issue.  Do you have `<script>` tags in your file.js?

Comment: you have not return any value from that function and did it print undefined on console 2nd time.?

Comment: "This **returns** undefined" is somewhat confusing... (as you'll see from the array of completely different comments/answers) - are you saying it calls the externalFunction ok, but is *logging* "undefined"?  Or are you saying "externalFunction" is undefined?

Comment: not possible, invalid question

Comment: Stack overflow is a **very active place**. If you post a question, please *stick around* so you can respond to requests for clarification from people trying to help you.

Comment: *"I should clarify that the div which contains the input element is hidden. `style="display: none;"` Would this make a difference?"* No, none at all. Again: Please update the question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (even if it can't be runnable, you can quote the **exact** contents of the absolute minimum files to make it happen).

Comment: The val() function is returning 'undefined' hence he is seeing 'undefined' in the console. I'm having a very similar if not the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

> When I call the same function from a seperate js file it returns
>   undefined.

- If you mean the function returns undefined.

This is the correct behaviour because you **returned** nothing.

You have to use `return` statement.

```
function externalFunction() {
    return $("#amount").val();
}

let value=externalFunction();
console.log(value);
```

- if function is not found in your actual file.

Use **export** statement or `require` in order to make function visible in other file also.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the question, that's simply not possible.

Instead, I suspect that you aren't calling `externalFunction` at the same time you're calling the `console.log`. Instead, I suspect you're calling it earlier, before the input exists.

There are only two reasons `val` ever returns `undefined`:

1. You call it on an empty jQuery object (because nothing matched the selector, for instance, because you called the function too soon).
2. You call it on a jQuery object whose first element is not an `input` or `select` (and thus has no `value` property).